# Need Help adding a Subject

Tags: apex, trigger

I got this trigger to work, but when i went back to add a subject I keep getting compiling errors.

Can anyone help me?

```
trigger UserAfter on User (after update) {

    Map<Id, List<User>> mgrToUserMap = new Map<Id, List<User>>{};

        //Collect all the managers who have deactivated users
        for(User u : trigger.new){
            if (!u.IsActive && u.ManagerId != null){
                List<User> currUsers = mgrToUserMap.get(u.ManagerId);
                if(currUsers == null){
                    currUsers = new List<User>{};
                        mgrToUserMap.put(u.ManagerId, currUsers);
                }
                currUsers.add(u);
            }
        }// end for

    if(!mgrToUserMap.isEmpty()){
        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(mgrToUserMap.size());

        for(Id mgrId : mgrToUserMap.keySet()){

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTargetObjectId(mgrId);
            mail.saveAsActivity = false;

            //only send one email for all deactivated users per manager
            String emailBody = '';
            String emailSubject = '';
            for(User usr : mgrToUserMap.get(mgrId))

                //SEND LINKS TO REPORTS SHOWING ACCOUNTS, OPPORTUNITIES, CASES, 
                ACTIVITES OWNED BY DEACTIVATED USER
                emailSubject += '' + usr.FirstName + ' ' + usr.LastName + ' has been 
                deactivated in Salesforce';
                emailBody += 'The following user has been deactivated in Salesforce:<b>  
                ' + usr.FirstName + ' ' + usr.LastName + ' </b>has left the 
                organization.<p>' +
                'Their Accounts/Contacts and Opportunities will be reassigned to you 
                shortly. If they have not yet been reassigned, they will appear on the 
                following Reports.<p>'+

                'Accounts with Contacts: 

                https://aquent.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/00O6A000003HPJuUAO/view<p>'+

            'Opportunities: 
                https://aquent.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/00O6A000003HPKEUA4/view<p>'+

            'Once you own the record, you are able to reassign them to the user of 
                your choice by selecting the icon next to the Account Owner on the 
                record.<p>';


                mail.setHtmlBody(emailBody);

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to call Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity, since you're emailing users.

Comment: Also, you should be constructing a list of messages and sending all of the emails at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect you to get errors, because you've got multi-line string literals, which are invalid in Apex Code. Also, you forgot to include `{` and `}` around your for loop, which meant that the `usr` variable was out of scope. **Always** surround the body of an `if`, `for`, `while`, or `do` block with `{` and `}`. While the syntax allows you to not do so, you risk introducing bugs, as you've discovered.

Also, you do not need to reserve email capacity when emailing users; you have an unlimited number of those you can send daily. Finally, always put the mails in to a list and send them all at once. There's a limit of 10 Messaging.sendEmail calls per transaction, so you'll want to use as few as possible.

Here's the modified version with all of the preceding suggestions:

```
trigger UserAfter on User (after update) {

    Map<Id, List<User>> mgrToUserMap = new Map<Id, List<User>>{};

        //Collect all the managers who have deactivated users
        for(User u : trigger.new){
            if (!u.IsActive && u.ManagerId != null){
                List<User> currUsers = mgrToUserMap.get(u.ManagerId);
                if(currUsers == null){
                    currUsers = new List<User>{};
                        mgrToUserMap.put(u.ManagerId, currUsers);
                }
                currUsers.add(u);
            }
        }// end for

    if(!mgrToUserMap.isEmpty()){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] mails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
        for(Id mgrId : mgrToUserMap.keySet()){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTargetObjectId(mgrId);
            mail.saveAsActivity = false;

            //only send one email for all deactivated users per manager
            String emailBody = '';
            String emailSubject = '';
            for(User usr : mgrToUserMap.get(mgrId)) {

                //SEND LINKS TO REPORTS SHOWING ACCOUNTS, OPPORTUNITIES, CASES, 
                ACTIVITES OWNED BY DEACTIVATED USER
                emailSubject += '' + usr.FirstName + ' ' + usr.LastName + ' has been deactivated in Salesforce';
                emailBody += 'The following user has been deactivated in Salesforce:<b>' + 
                    usr.FirstName + ' ' + usr.LastName + ' </b>has left the organization.<p>' +
                    'Their Accounts/Contacts and Opportunities will be reassigned to you shortly. If they have not yet been reassigned, they will appear on the following Reports.<p>'+
                    'Accounts with Contacts: https://aquent.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/00O6A000003HPJuUAO/view<p>'+
                    'Opportunities: https://aquent.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/sObject/00O6A000003HPKEUA4/view<p>'+
                    'Once you own the record, you are able to reassign them to the user of your choice by selecting the icon next to the Account Owner on the record.<p>';
            }
            mail.setHtmlBody(emailBody);
            mail.setSubject(emailSubject);
            mails.add(mail);
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I'm certainly not a developer (shows I'm sure) but I dabble and and get dangerous. But this works now!